# Return unique records based on shared column in 3 tables

Tags: sql-server-2012, join, table

This is the database schema that I'm working with and I've included some sample data as an example of what is currently in the database.

```
CREATE TABLE Visits   ([ADATE] date, [AKEYTIME] varchar(10), [ATIME] varchar(10), [BOOK] varchar(10), [ID] varchar(100), [ACCOUNT] int,
                       [ADESC] varchar(100), [DEPARTMENT] varchar(100), [FINTIME] varchar (10), [FACILITY] varchar(10), [APPTNO] int);
CREATE TABLE CustList ([ACCOUNT] int, [FAMILY] int, [CLNAME] varchar(100), [CFNAME] varchar(100), [CMNAME] varchar(100), [CPHONE] varchar(12),
                       [CID] int, [SEX] varchar(1), [NICKNAME] varchar(100), [EMAIL] varchar(100));
CREATE TABLE Orders   ([ID] int, [DATETIME] datetime, [SSNO] int, [NAME] varchar(100), [ORDERDATE] date, [ORDERTIME] varchar(10),
                       [DONEDATE] date, [DONETIME] varchar(10), [PAGE] int, [ACCOUNT] int, [FACILITY] varchar(100));

INSERT INTO Visits
    ([ADATE], [AKEYTIME], [ATIME], [BOOK], [ID], [ACCOUNT], [ADESC], [DEPARTMENT], [FINTIME], [FACILITY], [APPTNO])
VALUES
    ('', '11:18', '11:18 AM', 'HD1_WC', 'SMITH, JOHN', '131456', 'REPAIR ORDER', 'HD', '11:35 AM', '', '2002467341'),
    ('', '15:21', '03:21 PM', 'XA1_NU', 'JONES, JANE', '343789', 'NEW PURCHASE', 'XA', '3:35 PM', '', '2002763299'),
    ('', '15:30', '03:30 PM', 'XA1_NU', 'JONES, JANE', '343789', 'NEW PURCHASE', 'XA', '3:35 PM', '', '2002763244')

INSERT INTO CustList
    ([ACCOUNT], [FAMILY], [CLNAME], [CFNAME], [CMNAME], [CPHONE], [CID], [SEX], [NICKNAME], [EMAIL])
VALUES
    ('131456', '131456', 'SMITH', 'JOHN', '', '111/222-3333', '131456', 'M', 'JOHN', 'JOHN@EMAIL.COM'),
    ('343789', '343789', 'JONES', 'JANE', '', '111/444-5555', '343789', 'F', 'JANIE', 'JANE@EMAIL.COM')

INSERT INTO Orders
    ([ID], [DATETIME], [SSNO], [NAME], [ORDERDATE], [ORDERTIME], [DONEDATE], [DONETIME], [PAGE], [ACCOUNT], [FACILITY])
VALUES
    ('0001457843', '', '343789', 'JONES, JANE', '', '03:35 PM', '', '', '2002763299', '343789', 'OFFICE 1'),
    ('0001457844', '', '343789', 'JONES, JANE', '', '03:35 PM', '', '', '2002763299', '343789', 'OFFICE 1'),
    ('0001457845', '', '343789', 'JONES, JANE', '', '03:35 PM', '', '', '2002763244', '343789', 'OFFICE 1'),
    ('0001457846', '', '343789', 'JONES, JANE', '', '03:35 PM', '', '', '2002763244', '343789', 'OFFICE 1'),
    ('0001237789', '', '131456', 'SMITH, JOHN', '', '11:35 AM', '', '', '2002467341', '131456', 'OFFICE 2'),
    ('0001237790', '', '131456', 'SMITH, JOHN', '', '11:35 AM', '', '', '2002467341', '131456', 'OFFICE 2')
;
```

I've been using the following query to return the email address of a customer.

```
WITH DistinctAccountsVisits
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ACCOUNT
    FROM Visits
    WHERE FINTIME IS NOT NULL
         AND ADATE = '1900-01-01'
    )

SELECT v.Account
    ,c.Email
FROM DistinctAccountsvisits v
JOIN CustList c ON c.Account = v.Account
```

Now I need to pull information on which facility the customer last visited and that information is stored in a third table called `Orders`.

Here is some sample output that shows the duplicate entries that are returned when running the query in the below answer.

```
ID       EMAIL            FACILITY

123456  cust1@email.com   LOCATION1
123456  cust1@email.com   LOCATION2
123456  cust1@email.com   LOCATION2
123456  cust1@email.com   LOCATION1
123456  cust1@email.com   LOCATION1
123456  cust1@email.com   LOCATION3
123456  cust1@email.com   LOCATION3
123456  cust1@email.com   LOCATION3
123456  cust1@email.com   LOCATION1
987654  cust2@email.com   LOCATION1
987654  cust2@email.com   LOCATION1
987654  cust2@email.com   LOCATION1
987654  cust2@email.com   LOCATION1
987654  cust2@email.com   LOCATION3
987654  cust2@email.com   LOCATION1
987654  cust2@email.com   LOCATION2
987654  cust2@email.com   LOCATION2
987654  cust2@email.com   LOCATION2
```

DB Fiddle Examples using SQL Server 2016:

- [Original query returning just the email address](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1db76747cb990492ea9eb75950bd1335)
- [Updated query returning duplicate records](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a82336c24144911be9c40d7cb7b35dd3)

The query I'm using above was originally given to me by someone on StackExchange in a question I asked 4 years ago. The person who answered that question also asked the same thing but posted an answer before I could respond. Maybe that will give you more insight as I don't know how to get the CREATE TABLE DDL, I don't even know what DDL means.

Here is a link to the original question: [Return unique records based on shared column in 2 tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174890/return-unique-records-based-on-shared-column-in-2-tables?noredirect=1#comment338705_174890)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you've provided, it seems like all you would need to do is another `JOIN` (which is an `INNER JOIN`) to the `@MasterList` table variable like this:

```
WITH DistinctAccountsVisits
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Account
    FROM @visits
    WHERE TimeOfVisit IS NOT NULL
         AND DateOfVisit = '2017-05-25'
    )

SELECT v.Account
    ,c.EmailAddress
    ,m.Facility
FROM DistinctAccountsvisits v
JOIN @CustList c ON c.Account = v.Account
JOIN @MasterList m ON v.Account = m.Account
```

If there's any issues with this, please let me know, and I can adjust accordingly. For example, this will filter out any rows from `@DistinctAccountsvisits` that don't relate to `@MasterList`. If you want to keep those rows in, then you can use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126275/discussion-on-answer-by-j-d-return-unique-records-based-on-shared-column-in-3-t).